# Is it possible to remove public/index.html from my Rails app by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have created a .railsrc file in home directory that currently creates new Rails apps with Postgres as default and doesn't bundle on startup. The file contains the following:

```
-d postgresql
--skip-bundle
```

Is there any way I can add an option to this file to stop rails from adding the default html page with each new Rails app I create?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use application templates, in your .railsrc, add something similar to this

```
--template ~/rails-template.rb
```

and in your template,

```
run "rm public/index.html"
```

[Here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) is the rails application templates guide.

You can do much more with templates. Here are more [examples](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates).

I hope it helps.